# Ext functor in derived categories

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, derived-functors, derived-categories

For any abelian category $A$ (with enough injectives), consider its derived category $D^b(A)$. Suppose we have a complex of this form $$0\to F\to L^{n+1}\to ... \to L^{1} \to G\to 0$$
which is exact. Furthermore we have $Ext^i(G,F)=0$, for $i>n$.

I want to conclude that $G\oplus F[-(n+1)]\cong [L^{n+1}\to ... \to L^{1}]$. It is said that this is implied by the vanishing of the $Ext$ functor, but I don't see **why the vanishing of the $Ext$ functor is necessary**. <s>There is a canonical map $G\oplus F[-n+1]\to L^{n+1}\to ... \to L^{1}$, which is a quasi-isomorphism, so the $Ext$ shouldn't be involved here?</s>

EDIT: I was mistaken as pointed out in the comments, so I somehow need the $Ext$ vanishing. Maybe it might be helpful to know that $Ext^i(G,F)=Hom_{D(A)}(G,F[i])$?

Maybe we can also consider the roof $G\leftarrow [ F\to L^{n+1}\to ... \to L^{1}]\to [0\to L^{n+1}\to ... \to L^{1} ] $, the left map being a quasi-isomorphism.

Comment: How do you construct the map $G \to [L^{n+1} \to \dots \to L^1]$?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem now, I got the arrows mixed up. I would still like to conclude the isomorphism though, with the help of the Ext-functor then I assume?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the distinguished triangle
$$
[0 \to L^{n+1} \to \dots \to L^1] \to [F \to L^{n+1} \to \dots \to L^1] \to F[n+1].
$$
Its middle term is quasi-isomorphic to $G$, hence the right map is zero by the vanishing of $Ext$'s, hence the first term is quasi-isomorphic to the sum $G \oplus F[n]$.

Comment: I assume you can argue that this is a distinguished triangle by looking at $F[n]\to [0 \to L^{n+1} \to \dots \to L^1] \to [F \to L^{n+1} \to \dots \to L^1]$ which is obviously a dist. triangle and then use the second axiom, which tells you that the shifted triangle will be distinguished aswell?